# What are the ways to successfully get out of the cave?

Tags: greedy-cave

I know that [escape scrolls](http://the-greedy-cave.wikia.com/wiki/Escape_Scroll) allows you to go back to the tavern screen and save your progress (experience, bonuses, gold items). Is there any other way to do it without those scrolls ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer is **NO**.

The only way to escape from the dungeons is to use an escape scroll.
Its been my observation that there usually is a scroll within the first three floors of any dungeon level you **start** at so loot every single thing till you find it.